# Who was La Forge's impostor in The Mind's Eye?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the TNG episode '[The Mind's Eye](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Mind%27s_Eye_(episode))' Geordi was replaced by an impostor that was sent to Risa in his place. This individual looks very similar to Geordi (human, male, black, similar height, build, etc) so how have the Romulans come into cooperation with such a person?

**Did he make any other appearances elsewhere? Are there any other sources (such as the novels) that can shed some light on his identity? Was he a hologram, a human replica, an android or something else entirely?**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, just like "how many licks it takes to get to the tootsie roll center of a tootsie pop" the world will never know this either =\

Comment: 3 licks the worlds known for years.

Comment: I'm curious why this is attracting downvotes...

Comment: I've not downvoted myself, but I'd suggest it's because it's entirely speculation-based: it's never stated in Canon who this person is.

Comment: @JonStory And only because, there is a small change of answering, this makes entire question a bad question in yours (and many others) opinion, right? "This is a bad question, because I can't answer". "We should not ask here questions, that are hard to answer" (why we should ask at all, then?). Doesn't this sound a little bit like paranoia? Define "curiosity", if it isn't asking questions, for which answer is not well known. Isn't asking such questions a base of Stack Exchange?

Comment: I've made a fairly substantial edit to make your question more focused. Feel free to rollback if you think I've gone too far.

Comment: @JonStory: "There is no answer because..." is also an answer.

Comment: Umm, didn't I just say I didn't downvote? Don't shoot the messenger, guys

Comment: @Richard Your edit is fine with me. No rollback needed nor required. Thanks.

Comment: @JonStory - FWIW, I'm not shooting! :) Just replying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's very little information about this [individual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Aikins). He's not seen again in the episode nor does he appear in any future episodes.

The [shooting script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/198.txt) refers to him as a [human operative](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Unnamed_Humans_(24th_century)#La_Forge_double) so we can rule out the more exotic possibilities (hologram, android, Romulan in disguise) but that's about it.

> Then Taibak motions to someone else, and a **BLACK HUMAN in a Starfleet
>   uniform steps out from behind the lights.** The man puts on a fake VISOR
>   just like Geordi's. Taibak walks around the man, studying him, then
>   nods with satisfaction.
>
> **TAIBAK :** *Good. Very good.*
>
> As Geordi's double starts to leave...
>
> **TAIBAK** (casual, serious) : *Do not enjoy yourself too much on Risa.*
>
> Geordi's double nods, then EXITS.

Comment: A perfect answer, thank you. Still thinking, what is wrong with my question or all these downvoters?

Comment: @trejder - You've made it a bit too wide by asking about "any" traitors.

Comment: FYI - I can't find it, but I seem to recall a mention elsewhere of Romulan "collaborators" within the Federation. I'm pretty sure it was on an episode of TNG or DS9, but that's still a very large target.

Comment: @Omegacron - POssibly "The Drumhead"? One of Picard's junior officers is accused of secretly being a Romulan.

Comment: I thought of that one, but was thinking more of a wide-reaching, off-hand comment. It may have been in that episode of DS9 where Section 31 recruits Dr. Bashir at a medical conference. I vaguely remember the comment being something like "We never know who in the Federation is really a Romulan collaborator." or similar.

Comment: The Drumhead is the only episode in which the words "Romulan collaborator" appear

Answer (score -3):

It was a Romulan surgically altered to look human.

Comment: Can you back up this bold statement with some evidence? The script states that he's a human.

Comment: He can't because there is none.  But it does remain a possibility because we know that there black Vulcans.  I believe that we've also seen a black Romulan.